# Kubernetes: kubectl exec command different behaviour from C# program

Tags: c#, kubernetes, exec, kubectl

I have a Kubernetes cluster with a **deployment** workload resource and a storage mounted (persistent volume claim).
The deployment resource runs a container with a Minecraft server, containing file `server.properties`.

#### Wanted Behaviour

I want to change a value from that file, from a C# application, using `kubectl exec` and `sed` command:

```bash
kubectl exec deployment/test-mc -- sed -i 's|^gamemode=.*|gamemode=creative|' server.properties
```

If I launch this command from a terminal (not from the application) it works just fine, and the file gets updated with the new value. To check that I used `kubectl exec deployment/test-mc -- cat server.properties`.

#### Problem

When I try launching the same command **from the C# application, it doesn't work**. That's the code I use to run the command:

```cs
private string ExecCommand(string serverName, string command)
{
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        FileName = "kubectl",
        Arguments = $"exec deployment/{serverName} -- {command}",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };

    var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = processStartInfo
    };

    process.Start();

    var commandOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();

    return commandOutput;
}

public void ChangeGamemode(string serverName, string newGamemode)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Command: sed -i 's|^gamemode=.*|gamemode={newGamemode}|' server.properties");
    var commandOutput = ExecCommand(serverName, $"sed -i 's|^gamemode=.*|gamemode={newGamemode}|' server.properties");
    Console.WriteLine($"Output: {commandOutput}");
}
```

But when I check the content of `server.properties` using `kubectl exec deployment/test-mc -- cat server.properties`, the value is still unchanged.

#### Further Information

I know for sure that I can access the deployment resource, since I tried creating a file from the C# application and it succeeded:

```cs
// From C# Application
ExecCommand(serverName, "touch test.txt");
```

File list from terminal:

```bash
> kubectl exec deployment/test-mc -- ls -la
total 46748
[...]
-rw-rw-rw-  1 minecraft minecraft     1313 Jul  3 10:46 server.properties
-rw-r--r--  1 root      root             0 Jul  3 11:23 test.txt
[...]
```

---

Any help will be kindly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var commandOutput = ExecCommand(serverName, "sed -i 's|^gamemode=.*|gamemode={newGamemode}|' server.properties");
```

Did you just forget to put `$` in front of `"sed -i 's|^gamemode=.*|gamemode={newGamemode}|' server.properties"`?

It should be:

```
var commandOutput = ExecCommand(serverName, $"sed -i 's|^gamemode=.*|gamemode={newGamemode}|' server.properties");
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot it while copy and pasting the method in the question, but it was not the problem :'( (I edited the question)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I still haven't figured out why it doesn't work but managed to find a workaround.

#### Workaround Solution

I created a **shell script** that does what I need: updates a property of the `server.properties` file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

property=$1 # property to change
newVal=$2   # value to assign to the property

sed -i "s/^${property}=.*/${property}=${newVal}/" server.properties
```

which I call from the C# application, passing the values I need, as follows:

```cs
ExecCommand(serverName, $"/bin/bash update-server-property.sh gamemode {newValue}");
```

This way the file gets updated as it should :)